# Recursion Function in Graph Path Finding

Tags: c#, recursion, path

I scripted the following recursion function to calculate all of the possible paths from a target node to a start node in a graph using adjacency matrix.

```
private Stack<string> TestCaseGeneration(int TargetStateIndex, double[,] adjacancy, Stack<string> TotalResults = null, Stack<string> CarrierStack = null, int StartStateIndex = 0)
{
    Stack<string> Result = CarrierStack;
    Result.Push(TargetStateIndex.ToString() + " - ");

    if (TargetStateIndex == StartStateIndex)
    {
       TotalResults.Push(StackToSingleString(Result));
       return TotalResults;
    }
    else
    {
       List<string> neighbours = ListNeighbourLeadingToTargetNode(TargetStateIndex, adjacancy, EventIndex);
       int NumberOfNeighbours = neighbours.Count;
       if (NumberOfNeighbours != 0)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfNeighbours; i++)
           {
              return TestCaseGeneration(int.Parse(neighbours[i].ToString()), adjacancy, TotalResults, Result, StartStateIndex);
           }
        }
     }
     else return null;
  }
```

The issue is `return` int the `for` loop, how can I fix it?

Comment: `if (NumberOfNeighbours != 0)` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @user1666620 it's recursion.

Comment: whats the problem with the return in the for loop? other than the fact that it won't actually loop of course.

Comment: @user1666620 exactly

Comment: ignore the fact that it is recursive think of it as just another function. what do you want the method to return, and then put that return statement after the loop. You're returning a stack of strings, so populate the stack in the for loop, and return it after.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to return anything set the `return null;` before the last `}`

If you put the `return null;` in a if else statement the compiler knows not all code paths return a value!

**EDIT**

I see your problem now sorry.

You need to create a variable wich you return at the end.
In the if statement you can edit the variable.

If the variable is never edited the default value of the variable is returned!

Comment: I tried it. Changed the last `return null;` to `result = null;` and `return result;`
Same result.

Answer (score 0):

The think your code will always return a value. I suggest you throw an exception just before the last } of the method: It will compile and you get a nice chance to see your code in action! If it throws the exception, you know when it was not going to return a value.

Answer (score 0):

As it has been pointed out your else statement does nothing. Consider laying out your method in layman's terms:

```
method(){
    if(something){
        // do stuff
        return value
    }
    else{
     // do something else but,
     // never do anything with this information
    }
    return null
}
```

This is basically what your method looks like when you break it down. The else statement does things, but those things are never used anywhere.

Suppose inside that else statement you call the recursive function which recursively calls 1000 more times. At the end of this loop it will return either null or some value back to the else statement.

That else statement then does nothing with the return value, then returns null.

That recursive call is basically useless unless it, too, is returned.

Consider trying:

```
private Stack<string> TestCaseGeneration(int TargetStateIndex, double[,] adjacancy, Stack<string> TotalResults = null, Stack<string> CarrierStack = null, int StartStateIndex = 0)
{
    Stack<string> Result = CarrierStack;
    Result.Push(TargetStateIndex.ToString() + " - ");

    if (TargetStateIndex == StartStateIndex)
    {
       TotalResults.Push(StackToSingleString(Result));
       return TotalResults;
    }
    else
    {
       int NumberOfNeighbours = ListNeighbourLeadingToTargetNode(TargetStateIndex, adjacancy, EventIndex).Count;
       if (NumberOfNeighbours != 0)
       {
           for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfNeighbours; i++)
           {
           return TestCaseGeneration(i, adjacancy, TotalResults, Result, StartStateIndex);
           }
        }
     }
     return null;
  }
```

Note that I added a return statement to the recursive call within the else statement.

Comment: Thanks leigero. I think you're right. I changed it as you asked but you are putting a return in a for loop which means after the first execution of the loop it will be returned and rest of the loop will remain unfinished. Meaning that compiler gives _Unreachable Code Detected_ warning.
Additionally, it won't fix _not all paths returns a value_ error.
The thing is, if I comment the for statement it will be fine. So **for statement** is the issue. Have to figure it out there